# NullPointerException on Mockito verify

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

**The problem:** Mockito throws an NPE in the test code statement, specifically the `verify` call with an argument matcher, with no further indication of the cause than the test code line.

The actual Exception when executing the test code is not only lacking information, but is also misleading:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at de.example.testing.TmpTest.testSomething(TmpTest.java:31)

Very shrunk down example of the code to be tested:

```
class Medium {
    void setLock(boolean locked) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // and other functionality ...
}
```

Testing code:

```
@Test
void testSomething() {
    // call testing code
    
    verify(_medium, never())
        .setLock(any()); // <-- NPE
}
```

In this example, `_medium` is a valid Mock and the execution of `verify(_medium, never())` also returns a non-null MockitoMock instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The solution** was: You cannot use `any()` to match arguments of primitive types.

In this case, Mockito offers `anyBoolean()`, as for all other primitives. However, due to the NPE, this is not obvious and may result in an extensive search and headscratching.

Comment: Thank you. This error catches me every time. I wonder why other Mockito errors are often quite verbal (trying to call `verify` on a not mocked class) and this one is just not at all.